# How to redraw pixels on a 2DTexture without it flickering

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

I would like to draw a line on a 2DTexture within unity. This works well within the editor. However, in compiled builds it will flicker as it fills the pixels of the texture with clear colour then re-draws the line.

Here's my drawling code:

```
public void DrawLineWithMouse (Vector2 _middleVector)
{
    tex.SetPixels(fillPixels); // Fills texture with an array of clear pixels
    Vector3 newMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    newMousePos.z = 0;
    int x0 = ((int)newMousePos.x)/RenderingManager.pixelSize  / thickness; //Screen.width-
    int y0 = ((int)newMousePos.y)/RenderingManager.pixelSize  / thickness; //Screen.height-
    int x1 =  (int)_middleVector.x - (x0 - (int)_middleVector.x );
    int y1 =  (int)_middleVector.y - (y0 - (int)_middleVector.y );
    DrawLineHelper(tex, x0, y0, x1, y1, Color.yellow); // redraws the line

    tex.Apply();
}
```

I do not get flickering when I create a new texture then apply it. However, this is very, very expensive and for testing purposes only.

```
    public void DrawLineWithMouse (Vector2 _middleVector)
{
    tex = new Texture2D(Screen.width/RenderingManager.pixelSize / thickness, Screen.height/RenderingManager.pixelSize / thickness);
    tex.SetPixels(fillPixels);
    tex.SetPixels(fillPixels);
    tex.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;



    Vector3 newMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    newMousePos.z = 0;
    int x0 = ((int)newMousePos.x)/RenderingManager.pixelSize  / thickness; //Screen.width-
    int y0 = ((int)newMousePos.y)/RenderingManager.pixelSize  / thickness; //Screen.height-
    int x1 =  (int)_middleVector.x - (x0 - (int)_middleVector.x );
    int y1 =  (int)_middleVector.y - (y0 - (int)_middleVector.y );
    DrawLineHelper(tex, x0, y0, x1, y1, Color.yellow);
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Comment: Curious about how you're calling `DrawLineWithMouse()`. Are you calling it in `Update` or `FixedUpdate`?

Comment: `if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){drawLineUtility.DrawLineWithMouse(startMousePointInPixels);}` within Update

Answer (score 0):

It's flicking because apply is an expensive operation. [The documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) states:

> This is a potentially expensive operation, so you'll want to change as many pixels as possible between Apply calls.

You have to find a way to do less calls to `DrawLineWithMouse`. What's the best solution, that's up to you and depends on what you are doing.

One alternative is to accumulate deltas of mouse movement and draw after *x* milliseconds. Another alternative is to draw a mesh on top of the texture instead of changing the texture, and then only change the texture when necessary, if ever (note that you can use a *RenderTexture* here to easily draw the mesh in the texture).

Finally, lowering the resolution of the texture makes `Apply` run faster.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but This is incorrect. It is because I am`tex.SetPixels(fillPixels);` Fill pixels is an array of clear pixels. It then redraws the line. I'll update my question so that its clearer

Comment: I still don't understand why you have to call `SetPixels` and clear everything instead of calling `SetPixel` to draw pixel by pixel, only changing what you want. Wait... ...is this the right answer?

Comment: @Jim did you get it working? did you see my message?

Comment: Thanks for following up Roberto. Sadly no.